# ajaxForm().submit() not working in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, ajaxform

I have the following code for a form that uploads an image on submit. Works fine in all current browsers except IE (no versions work):

```
$('#photo-upload').live('change', function()
{
$('#'+currentId+' > img').css('opacity',0);
$('#'+currentId).addClass('hasImg');
index = currentId.replace(/place-/i, "");
$('#photo-index').val( index );
$("#imageform").ajaxForm({ target: '#photo-'+index }).submit();

// initialize photo settings
photo_x_pos = 0;
photo_y_pos = 0;
photo_angle = 0;

});
```

And the form HTML:

```
<form id="imageform" action="/orders/photo_upload" method="post">
    <div id="upload">
        <input type="file" name="data[Photo][image]" id="photo-upload" />
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="data[Photo][index]" id="photo-index" />
<input type="hidden" name="data[Photo][width]" id="photo-width" />
<input id="uploadthephoto" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

It seems that what is breaking in IE is the form is not submitting. `#photo-upload` is an `<input type="file"/>` element. `#imageform` is the id of the form. So ideally, the form submits with target `#photo-0` when the user selects the file, and returns the uploaded image.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there some alternative way to submit the ajaxForm that doesn't break IE?

Comment: alert all of the values leading up the to ajaxForm to confirm that they contain what you expect them to.